# how to check permission on a document whether it has any update/read permission or not, if there is no permission on the document in marklogic?

Tags: security, permissions, marklogic

how to check permission on a document whether it has any update/read permission or not, if there is no permission on the document in marklogic?
For example :

```
    let $schema := fn:doc($schema-uri)/xs:schema
    return
       else if (fn:exists ($schema)) then ()    
       else
          fn:error(xs:QName('e:no-schema'), 'The schema does not exist.', $schema-uri)";
```

In this case, if $schema-uri does not have any permission it will goes to else condition as fn:doc($schema-uri) does not able to read the document and it is mapped to "The schema does not exist" error  which is incorrect as the schema exist but have not any permissions on it.
So how can I handle it in condition if the schema exist but does not have any permission on it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the permissions of a document, [xdmp:document-get-permissions()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-get-permissions).

This will get you a sequence of permissions. In that will be references to role-ids. If you want to know the associated role names, You can pass the IDs to [xdmp:role-names()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:role-name)

However... I strongly suggest that you refrain from adding documents into any database (modules, schemas, etc) without permissions.  As quickly as possible step away from using Admin for any type of work.

Comment: xdmp:document-get-permissions() does give empty sequence, when there is no permission on uri or if the uri does not exist, so how should we distinguish that either uri exist or there is no permission on the uri.

Comment: OK. that's a different topic from the original question.  fn:exists(fn:doc($uri)) will tell you of there is a document at that URI.  *however* if the user making the call does not have read access to the document to begin with, then  - due to security - you will not know if the URI exists  - because you don't have permission to know about the document...  Moral of the story: define a security model and apply it to your artifacts - know who can read, execute, change based on roles.  Nothing should "exist, but not have permissions"